# Does String Pool in Java behaves like LRU cache?

Tags: java, string, jls, lru, string-pool

Strings are immutable and are managed in String pool. I wish to know as how this pool is managed. If there are large number of String literals being used in an application, ( I understand String builder should be used when modifications like append, replace operations are more ) then Pool enhances the performance of the application by not recreating the new String objects again and again but using the same objects present in the pool, this is possible as Strings are immutable and doing so has no ill effect.

My question is as how this `String Pool` is managed. If in case there is huge frequency of some 'k' Strings and there may be few other String objects which are once created and not being used again. There may be other newer String literals being used.

In cases like these does String Pool behaves like LRU cache, holding
the references to the latest used literals and removing the older not
used strings from the pool ?

Does String pool has a size or can we control it in our application ?

Edit :

Usually we give size to the custom object pools we implement. I wonder why feature like LRU is not there for Sting Pools. This could have been a feature. In case of large Strings also there would not have been problem. But I feel its the way it has been implemented but I just wanted to know as why its not there, I mean its not there for some valid reason, having this feature would have resulted in some ill effects. If some one could throw some light on those ill effects, it will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String pool is not an LRU cache, since entries aren't taken out unless GC'd.

There are 2 ways to get entries in the String pool. String literals go there automatically, and new entries can be added with `String.intern()` unless the `String` already exists in the pool, in which case a reference to it is returned.

The values **are** garbage collected if there are no more references to them, which for String literals (e.g. String constants) can be a bit harder than ones that were `intern()`ed.

The implementation has changed a lot between Java 6 and Java 8 (and even between minor versions). The default size of the String pool is apparently `1009`, but it can be changed with `-XX:StringTableSize=N` (since Java 7) parameter. This size is the table size of an internal hash table, so it can be tuned higher if you're using a lot of `intern()` (for String literals, it should be plenty). The size affects only the speed of `intern()` call, not the amount of Strings you can intern.

Basically unless you're using `intern()` heavily (presumably for a good reason), there's very little reason to worry about the String pool. Especially since it's no longer stored in `PermGen`, so it can't cause `OutOfMemoryErrors` very easily anymore.

[Source](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/).